# How to split a dataframe by factor but discontinuous row should be in different group

Tags: r

For example:

```
> a <- 1:10
> c <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
> dt <- data.frame(a,c)
> dt
    a c
1   1 1
2   2 1
3   3 1
4   4 0
5   5 0
6   6 0
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 1
10 10 0
```

I want the data should be seperated in 4 group by c:
The first group:

```
        a c
    1   1 1
    2   2 1
    3   3 1
```

The second one:

```
    a c
1   4 0
2   5 0
3   6 0
```

The third one:

```
    a c
1   7 1
2   8 1
3   9 1
```

The forth one:

```
    a c
1  10 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping variable and use that to `split` the 'dt' into a `list` of `data.frame`s.

```
library(data.table)
split(dt, rleid(dt$c))
```

Or as @ZheyuanLi mentioned, the `rle` from `base R` can be used to create the grouping variable

```
split(dt, with(rle(dt$c), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))
```